# ASP.Net Cast Control to TextBox and fire event

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

in the main page i call this class to change the visibility of the control

```
Web_Helper.ChangeStateControl(DESCRIZIONETextbox, false);
```

in WebHelper after i changed the visibility i need to fire the event associated to the control if exists, is this possible?

```
public class Web_Helper
{
    public static void ChangeStateControl(Control control, bool visible)
    {
         if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            ((TextBox)control).Visible = visible;
            ((TextBox)control).Text = String.Empty;
            //if control.hasEvent("TextChanged)
            //   control.TextChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the control doesn't exist, how can you change its visibility?

Comment: I think he meant if TextChanged is subscribed

Comment: sorry for my bad english, I meant if the event exists